# How do I register different events in a supply in Raku?

Tags: asynchronous, events, promise, raku

Hopefully "events" isn't a misnomer in Rakuland. As far as I understand, [Supplies](https://docs.raku.org/language/concurrency.html#Supplies) are the Raku equivalent for "events" in other programming languages such as NodeJS. In NodeJS, you can register different events which can be targeted specifically with `emit`'s first parameter. Is it possible to do this in Raku?

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('start', () => {
  console.log('started');
});

eventEmitter.on('end', (value) => {
  console.log(`ended ${value}` );
});

eventEmitter.emit('start');
eventEmitter.emit('end', 23);
```

I'm reading [A nice supplies: syntactic relief for working with asynchronous data](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/day-14-a-nice-supplies-syntactic-relief-for-working-with-asynchronous-data/) (which I haven't finished yet) and I see jnthn implements a subscription mechanism with `subscribe` and `send` so I'm wondering if that's the way to go about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `Supply` is a suitable mechanism for event distribution, but unlike `EventEmitter` it doesn't directly have a named events mechanism - in part because Raku already has plentiful ways to filter and dispatch, which can be reused for the purpose.

The most common approach is to use typed messages:

```
class Start { }

class End {
    has $.value
}
```

Given a `Supplier` we can emit these:

```
my $supplier = Supplier.new;
$supplier.emit(Start); # Don't need an instance if there's no data
$supplier.emit(End.new(value => 42));
```

The receiving end is the `Supply`:

```
my $supply = $supplier.Supply;
```

Typically, the thing doing the emitting keeps the `Supplier` private and returns the `Supply`, which only allows receiving.

On the receiving end, we have a multitude of ways to work with the events. For example, we could translate your example most directly as:

```
$supply.grep(Start).tap: {
    say "started";
}

$supply.grep(End).tap: {
    say "ended {.value}";
}
```

If using a structured `supply` or `react` block that'd be:

```
react {
    whenever $supply.grep(Start) {
        say "started";
    }
    whenever $supply.grep(End) {
        say "ended {.value}";
    }
}
```

Or one might prefer to use the `when` match construct:

```
$supply.tap: {
    when Start { say "started"; }
    when End { say "ended {.value}"; }
}
```

Which again works similarly in the structured approach:

```
react {
    whenever $supply {
        when Start { say "started"; }
        when End { say "ended {.value}"; }
    }
}
```

Or one could write multiple dispatch routines and subscribe those:

```
multi process(Start) {
    say "started"
}
multi process(End (:$value)) { # Can destructure the message in the signature
    say "ended $value"
}
$supply.tap(&process);
```

Besides the flexibility of approach on the receiving end, another advantage is that typos in class names will be detected at compile time, whereas typos in strings - at least if you're not in TypeScript or something similar - are likely to end up being noticed until rather later.

Comment: I keep relearning that not only is Raku quite expressive but also quite cohesive (i.e., features are reused all over the place in a sensible manner); it never occurred to me to use its multiple dispatch mechanism to this end. Thanks a lot, Jonathan! I'll go back to the Raku compiler, try your code snippets, and continue reading your article :)!